# While installing a theme named as The7 in wordpress getting Error

Tags: wordpress, datastax-astra

Import failed due to repository server error. Please try again in 30-60 minutes. If the problem persists, please don't hesitate to contact our support.

i m getting this error i have tried this :
define('FS_METHOD','direct');
as they said on their support page but it's not working.

Comment: then i would contact their support like they said

Answer (score 1):

I found it it was issue with server configuration.
Make sure that your server meets the requirement of the7 theme installation configuration. in your case there may be duplicate activation key